Connecting to remote server failed using WinRM from PowerShell In VM
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" -Force

$username = "xdfsdff"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

$ipAddress = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" # Enclose IP address in quotes

# Attempt to create a new PSSession
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ipAddress -Credential $credential

# Check if $session is null
if ($session -ne $null) {
    # If session is successfully created, execute script block
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        # Your script goes here
        Get-Date
    }

    # Close the session
    Remove-PSSession $session
} else {
    Write-Host "Failed to establish a remote session."
}

I have connect Azure VM Machine Using Powershell Using Above script but facing below issues

New-PSSession : [172.174.154.189] Connecting to remote server 172.174.154.189 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the
operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the
WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote
computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.


Make sure to check WinRM is set up to allow remote access to this machine for management, you can enable windows remoting on the destination computer : WinRM quickconfig and also set local firewall to all using the cmdlet: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" dir=in action=allow service=any enable=yes profile=any localport=5985 protocol=tcp

Same issues please help me

New-PSSession : [172.174.154.189] Connecting to remote server 172.174.154.189 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see

Have you checked the listening port by "netstat -aon"


WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer.

The above error indicates that WinRM is not enabled for remote management on remote server, You can enable it by using the appropriate cmdlet.
WinRM quickconfig


Note: If you encounter any errors while enabling remote management, simply change the network from public to private and then attempt to execute the same command again.


Open port 5986 on the firewall by using the cmd.
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5986 "WinRM over HTTP"

Allow the remote machine as trusted host on the client by using cmd.
 winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="Remote_IP"}'

Here is the full script.
    winrm quickconfig -transport:http or winrm quickconfig
    
    netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5986 "WinRM over HTTP"
    
    winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="Remote_IP"}'
    
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welcome@123$" -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("Venkat", $password)
    
    $ipAddress = "Remote-Server_IP"
    
    # Attempt to create a new PSSession
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ipAddress -Credential $credential
    
    
    # Check if $session is null
    if ($session -ne $null) {
        # If session is successfully created, execute script block
        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            # Your script goes here
            Hostname
        }
    
        # Close the session
        Remove-PSSession $session
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failed to establish a remote session."
    }

Output:



Same issues not resolve please help

Have you enabled remote management? if yes ,restart the winrm service and check again.

Above All Step Performs please help me

New-PSSession : [172.174.154.189] Connecting to remote server 172.174.154.189 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see

Are you facing any error while running the cmd :winrm quickconfig?

No Please Help Me

Share the winrm quickconfig result screenshot.
